# Excel formulas for splitting and combining IF, AND, MIN

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am having some issues with a couple of formulas in excel. I have three rows of data for three people that are splitting the values equally until two of the people meet a max number. then the values all go to a single person. Here is the criteria

row 1 has a max at 800
row 2 does not have a max
row 3 has a max at 300

formula for row 1 `=MIN(800, SUM (D1:BF3)/3)`
formula for row 2 `=IF(AND((BG3=300),(BG1=800)),(SUM(D1:BF3)-1100),(SUM(D1:BF3)/3))`
formula for row 3 `= MIN(300, SUM (D1:BF3)/3)`

here's the raw data and the totals for each row using these formulas

Row 1: R1=10, U1=50, AC1=20 total in BG1= 513
Row 2: R2=10, AC2= 20 total in BG2 = 513
Row 3: N3=100, R3=10, W3=1250, Z3=50, AC3=20  total in BG3= 300

the actual total of all cells is 1540. Row 3 has a total of 300 so Row 1 and 2 totals should be 1540-300=1240 /2 = 620 for BG1 and 620 For BG2. As you can see BG1 and BG2 are short.

What i need is to take all cells for each of these people and divide them by the 3 of them, once row 3 hits 300 then divide all (row 1, 2 and 3) by 2 and so Row 1 and 2 totals continue to add up, once Row 1 totals hits 800 then Row 2 total will continue to increase total all cells (row 1,2,3)

would the formula for row 2 and 1 need an OR in there somewhere?

Hopefully this isn't too confusing. If i could attach the sheet that may make it a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula for BG3 is fine.  BG1 needs to be adjusted for the case where BG3 is 300:

```
=MIN(800,IF(BG3=300,(SUM(D1:BF3)-300)/2,SUM(D1:BF3)/3))
```

Similar for BG2:

```
=IF(BG3=300,IF(BG1=800,SUM(D1:BF3)-1100,(SUM(D1:BF3)-300)/2),SUM(D1:BF3)/3)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this info. BG1 is now showing the correct data but I can't get BG2 correct. Right now I have: IF(BG5=300,IF(BG3=800),SUM(D3:BF5)-1100,(SUM(D3:BF5)-300/2,SUM(D3:BF5)/3) and it's throwing out an error. Right now since BG3=300 but BG1 does not equal 800 BG2 should total up to 620, just like BG1 does. Once BG1 hits 800 then it should stop totaling.

Comment: I see a number of errors, including a typo I copied from your original formula.  I fixed the formula in the answer, but it looks like you introduced some errors in retyping it as shown in your comment.  Try copy and paste from the answer, or verify character by character.

Comment: This answer implements the logic as it's described in the question.  However, Máté Juhász's answer accomplished the same result in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified formulas according to your logic:

- your formula for row 3 is correct: `= MIN(300, SUM (D1:BF3)/3)`
- for row 1: `=MIN(800, (SUM(D1:BF3)-BG3)/2)`
  It's half the amount left after subtracting row 3 value, but not more then 800
- formula for row 2 `=SUM(D1:BF3)-BG1-BG3`
  In any cases it's the total sum minus the sun if the other two rows.

Comment: Good observation.  I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: While my answer gives optimized formulas, yours is also very helpful correcting the original formulas, I don't think it should be deleted.

Comment: OK, but your answer is better.

Comment: I actually was able to use a combo of both answers to achieve what i needed. Thank you both. Now do i mark this as answered? And how do I do that?